# Is this case an overuse of abstraction?

Tags: oop

We are using a library provided by someone else. Of late due to changes in that library our project has 500 errors. When migrating to the new library we found that only 15 APIs are failing and 500 errors are repetitive (multiples occurrences of those 15 errors, as same calls are used at so many times).

So, for migration I proposed creating another internal static wrapper class, that wraps those library API calls. Because if library were to change again we will have less code to change and thus code becomes easier to maintain in future. And also by wrapping calls we avoid human errors (or unintended(overloaded) API usages).

But some folks here, don't see the point in having another wrapper class, which they feel is *totally* unnecessary. Their sole point of argument is that as most API changes are just one liners we can always change them using CTRL+H (Find and replace). And they also say that this extra abstraction that I am suggesting, takes away the readability (as it hides the actual API call behind another method name (even though meaningful) ) for the coder/reader.

Whats the best approach here? Am I wrong with my suggestions?

Comment: This is not a bad idea. Don't let the nay-sayers get you down. If they insist on removing this abstraction, then next time *they* can be the ones to fix the 500+ library-dependency compiler problems.

Comment: And, using Find/Replace on the Entire Solution guarantees hours of fun for the whole team..

Comment: SWeko: I think there's a joke here I'm missing.  Is there a situation where a global find/replace could cause "hours" of effort for more than the person doing the find/replace?

Comment: Usually the folks that think that Find/Replace is a good solution, also think that shared folders are a good enough source code repository (a real, and unfortunate story indeed)

Comment: SWeko, your stories send shivers up my spine.

Comment: @SWeko: These stories sound like an alternative to ghost stories that programmers would tell around a campfire.

Comment: A thing I (kinda) omitted is that it was (a younger and greener, cca 2004) me that did the Find/Replace :) . As they say, wisdom comes from experience, experience comes from lack of wisdom.

Comment: @SWeko: Hehe... The ghost story equivalent of "...and you know how I *know* that story was true? Because... I *WAS* the driver of that haunted bus!!!"  (kids scream and run away from the campfire, grownups laugh and have another beer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a relatively common practice to wrap unstable APIs and libraries with custom wrappers. 
One common use, for example, is to translate exceptions of that library into your nomenclature of exceptions.

More generally these wrappers are known as an Adapter, though Adapters (IMHO) are more meant for providing functionality needed by one side while hiding the exact "language" of the other side, not because the other side is unstable.

You mentioned the use of statics though - I'm generally not a big fan of using these. IMHO it is better sometimes to have an interface represent the functionality you need, and then have subtypes of that interface, when one of these subtypes uses the third party library. The advantage of that is that can one day switch to another vendor without changing every call in your system.

Either way, you're generally on the correct track. IMHO anyone who thinks CTRL-H is a valid refactoring tool is asking for trouble. Are they at least using getters and setters (Where applicable) in their code?

Also, the readability part is unclear to me. An adapter with a readable name is just as good as an original API with a readable name.

Comment: Yes, even I was confused with the readability part. But then that's what they said :). Probably they are suggesting that API call hidden in another wrapper might not make the reader aware of the API's syntax/usage or something like that.

Comment: @Chandan: Why would the reader need to be aware of the underlying API syntax/usage? The whole point is that you want to minimize coupling on the underlying API

Comment: @Chandan: I tend to err on the side of too much abstraction generally - I mistrust any library that is not "standard" (i.e., not on the reliability of an establish apache project). I'm also a nut for API usability so I often write my own adapters.

Answer (score 12):

This is actually known as the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern, and it's specifically created with your exact problem in mind....

Adapter is specifically used to **NOT** add functionality, just to adapt an interface of an API to an interface expected by the caller. The interfaces are just a handy OO tool to implement the adapters function in a consistent and managable way, the pattern itself basically describes how to solve a problem.

Comment: I presume adapter is meant to do some adjustment(i.e adding logic etc) with the existing 3rd party functionality. I am just wrapping a call to a third party API. Would it still be eligible to be called Adapter? (as I am not defining interfaces either).

Answer (score 2):

If an API is changing, a wrapper is the only way to protect yourself.  If you've settled on a API that is changing you've got some big risks to your project.  Mitigating those risks with a wrapper also allows you to protect yourself if you want to switch to another library.

To implement the wrapper, you have to make the wrapper and do your search and replace.

Either way, you still have to touch all your calls due to the initial API change, so I don't see that the small extra investment is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say without knowing your code, but I feel like a facade/adapter is a good way to seprate api calls from your own code. I would not go so far to say it is necessary, but its clearer imho.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the API is doing and whether adding another layer really adds insulation/encapsulation or if it's merely adding another layer of indirection.  If a change in the API will necessitate a change in the public interface of your wrapper, it'll just get in the way.

A wrapper layer is best suited when you can expose the functionality at a level of abstraction that makes sense for your application, hiding the API flexibility that you don't need and standardizing how you access the functionality you do need.  This can also involve using function and parameter names more specific to your problem domain, which can reduce the conceptual difficulty of understanding how the API is integrated into your application.